# Decreasing memory allocation of an Scala object

Tags: scala

I want to optimize the following code for memory performance:

```
import com.madhukaraphatak.sizeof.SizeEstimator
object PlayGround extends App {
  val intSize = 100000
  case class VeryBigObj(int: List[Int])
  case class SimpleRels[N,E](nodes:Set[N], edges:Map[(N,N), E])
  val n0 = VeryBigObj(List.fill(intSize)(Random.nextInt))
  val n1 = VeryBigObj(List.fill(intSize)(Random.nextInt))
  val n2 = VeryBigObj(List.fill(intSize)(Random.nextInt))


  val sg = SimpleRels(Set(n0, n1, n2), Map((n0, n1) -> "n0--n1", (n1, n2) -> "n1--n2"))

  println(s"size of n0 ${SizeEstimator.estimate(n0)}")
  println(s"size of (n0, n1) ${SizeEstimator.estimate((n0, n1))}")
  println(s"size of Set(n0, n1, n2) ${SizeEstimator.estimate(Set(n0, n1, n2))}")
  println(s"size of sg ${SizeEstimator.estimate(sg)}")

}

//output
size of n0 4800032
size of (n0, n1) 9600072
size of Set(n0, n1, n2) 14400096
size of sg 14400312
```

Let's assume `VeryBigObj` has a very large memory footprint. In `SimpleRels`, I want to have a set containing a bunch of these objects and another Map that contains some relationship between these objects. As far as I know (I can be wrong), Scala creates new immutable objects for the tuples and Set and Map and doesn't point to already defined immutable variables (am I right?). How can change `rels` so it just contains pointers to those variables and reduces the memory footprint of this object?

Edit: I use [SizeEstimator](https://github.com/phatak-dev/java-sizeof) to check the size of an object.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to C/C++, Java/Scala containers only store references.

In the shown code, `VeryBigObj` will only be created by `new VeryBigObj` (`new` can be omitted if it is `case class`).

Only following codes create `VeryBigObj`:

```
val n0 = new VeryBigObj(0)
val n1 = new VeryBigObj(1)
val n2 = new VeryBigObj(2)
```

And put them inside containers won't copy or create new instance of `VeryBigObj`. only references will be put into the container.

Comment: @Omid your estimator doesn't account that the memory is shared, because the references all point to the same objects in memory. So if `n0` and `n1` are both `4800032`, and `(n0, n1)` is `9600072`  then `9600072` is your combined total because we are reusing n1 and n0, you don't double count them.

Comment: Try `(0 to 1000000).map(x => (n1,n2)).toList` see if it can bloom. Note: avoid printing the list because print the list will surely bloom.